# Need help with jQuery conditional that removes container element based on matched text

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my markup:

```
  <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <ul class="eventslist">
            <li>This event would be discarded</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>...</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <ul class="eventslist">
            <li>Earnings - This event would be included</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>...</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I need help writing a conditional that would go through each UL class="eventslist" on the page, and check that the first LI under UL class="eventslist" contains the word "Earnings" (it can be anywhere in the text, and capitilization should be ignored). If it doesn't, the entire DIV wrapped around the UL should be removed along with everything inside it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to give those with earnings a specific ID? it will make this much easier... Seeing as you generate this using a server-side script, make the server code see if it.startsWith("Earning") and then add an ID to the li tag

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have control over the mark up - I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery would do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".eventslist").filter(function(){
        var text = $(this).children("li:first").text();
        return !/earnings/i.test( text );  
    }).closest("div").remove();
});
```

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dGKMj/2/

Comment: Yep. I was still writing my code when you posted yours. Glad I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.eventslist').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).find('li:first').text().match(/earnings/i);
}).parent().remove();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/cnMxw/)

Explanation:

- Runs `.filter()` on the `.eventslist` lists, and keeps only those that don't have `eanings` somewhere in the first `li`.
- Removes the parent (basically the `div`) of these lists. Instead of `parent()`, you can also use `closest('div')` if the markup could change. The most bulletproof would be to give a class to the parent `div`, and then use `closest('div.container')`.

Comment: thanks a lot bazmegakapa - I gave the check to Tomgrohl because he answered first but your's is just as good, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers work, I prefer the simplicity of jQuery selectors.

```
$('ul.eventslist > li:first-child').not(":contains('Earnings'), :contains('earnings')").closest('div').remove();
```

I think that this is much easier to read and update later. <-- This is my opinion

http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/QFbD2/3/

Comment: Having to specify two versions of `Earnings` does not make me say: "Hm, how easy it is to update this later!" I am not sure either if it would work.

Comment: The problem with this one is if the `.eventslist` list will have more than one list item, the code stops to work: http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/8Wx7x/.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - I wish that it wasn't case sensitive or that I could use some regular expression too.  But I don't see this as a big set back.  It is very clear what the selectors are doing and that is a plus.  Besides, two versions of 'Earnings' is exactly what he specified.

Comment: @natedavisolds If you add another `li` (I added one to the second `ul`) it will remove the `div` even if it should not. About your selectors: they work fine, just don't say they are more maintainable. For me, the syntax of `filter` is very intuitive for example.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - ah yes. I updated the selector to only check the first-child.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - I added that it was my opinion that it is easier.  Better?

Comment: thanks a lot natedavisolds - I like the elegance of this code, and I will keep it as an example for future use.